# Spring Security 6 and MySQL 8. Reserved keyword means defaults JdbcUserDetailsManager and schema not supported

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

MySQL 8.0 now has `groups` as a reserved keyword.

This means the default implementation for `JdbcUserDetailsManager` is throwing exceptions as it has not got the table name `groups` backticked/escaped.

And example of one of the queries is:

```
public static final String DEF_RENAME_GROUP_SQL = "update groups set group_name = ? where group_name = ?";
```

I am currently just redefining all these queries (and made a new table `user_groups`) to get around this but was wondering if there was a "better" way or should I raise this as a git issue?